# Can White walkers speak?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, Can white walkers speak? I haven't read the books but don't see evidence to the affirmative in the TV series.

If not, I'm interested in any communication theories.

Comment: Relevant on SF&F: [List of all languages in TWOIAF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156279/54887) which includes Skroth.

Answer (score 14):

**YES - They can speak.**

For the TV series, a language was invented called [Skroth](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Skroth).

> In an interview with Entertainment Weekly during Season 2, Executive Producers David Benioff and D.B. Weiss stated that "Skroth" is indeed the official name of the language used by the White Walkers. According to the interview, the inhuman (and unpronounceable) sounds of Skroth, "ice-cracking chatter", were created by Sound Designer Peter Brown.

The language they speak in the books is not named:

> The novel A Song of Ice and Fire clearly states that "the Others" ("White Walkers" in the TV series) speak a language with the voice "like the cracking of ice on a winter lake", but the name of the language is not given.